# How to push (not pull) prometheus metrics to otlp collector?

Tags: go, prometheus, open-telemetry

I have a service where it is running /metrics for prometheus. I need to PUSH already exist metrics to OTLP collector. How can I do it? Thank you in advance

I try prometheus exporter from sdk metrics, but it creates metrics anew. It is necessary that previously created prometheus metrics (example prometheus.CounterVec) were quickly converted to the format on the go OTLP for sending to OTLP collector

Comment: Please clarify: is this your service (you can change source code); are these metrics generated by you or are they some built-in metrics of some library?

Comment: @markalex, I have a lot of services that have prometheus metrics. I need to make the transition from pull-model (scrape prometheus) to push-model (in custom collector) as smooth as possible. it is necessary that the services do not rewrite the old metrics entirely, but with the help of connect sdk otlp convert them into otlp metrics format and send them to the collector. Have I answered your question?

Comment: No, my questions are: 1. Is it your app, and you can modify it? (Or do you need an outside service, that will convert metrics?) 2. If it's your app, how metrics are created now: by use of [this client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang), other clients or they are built-in metrics of some library that you use?

Comment: @markalex
1. yes
2. [now prometheus collects metrics](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/go-application/) without otlp sdk.
I want to understand how I can use a otlp sdk or any other library to set up push and not pull metrics

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with otlp sdk, but the general outline of what you'll need to do is as follows: iterate through the metrics registry, get all metrics with labels and values, and convert gathered data into otlp format.

Comment: @markalex, thank you, it would be very nice to see the solution in the code...

Comment: StackOverflow is not free code writing service: you write code and if it doesn't work or works not how intended - come here with [mre] to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenTelemetry Go SDK won't be able to read/transform metrics emitted by the Prometheus library directly.
It could only export metrics to the Prometheus client.

With that in mind, I think you should do this in two steps:

1: Start by switching your usage of the Prometheus library to emitting metrics with OpenTelemetry, while still exporting those metrics to Prometheus.

Since OpenTelemetry can export emitted metrics to Prometheus, you should be able to do this in atomic changes, one (or a few) metrics at a time.

See this example for a code sample on how to configure OpenTelemetry to export metrics to Prometheus: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go/blob/main/example/prometheus/main.go

2: Once all the metrics have been migrated and your application itself doesn't rely on the Prometheus library anymore, you can setup the OTLP exporter and remove the prometheus one so your metrics get pushed and not pulled anymore.